# Does the TCP header have a "Padding" field?

Tags: tcp

I found one image of the TCP header that shows a field called "Padding", and I found another image of the TCP header that don't show the "Padding" field:

[image]

[image]

Which one of these two images is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793.html)* has the answer. Padding is only used if there are options that are not a multiple of an even 32 bits:

> Padding:  variable
>
> The TCP header padding is used to ensure that the TCP header ends and
> data begins on a 32 bit boundary. The padding is composed of zeros.

There is also the official diagram:

> [3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793.html#section-3.1). Header
> Format
>
> TCP segments are sent as internet datagrams. The Internet Protocol
> header carries several information fields, including the source and
> destination host addresses
> [[2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793.html#ref-2)]. A TCP header
> follows the internet header, supplying information specific to the TCP
> protocol. This division allows for the existence of host level
> protocols other than TCP.
>
> TCP Header Format
>
> ```
>  0                   1                   2                   3
>  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |          Source Port          |       Destination Port        |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                        Sequence Number                        |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                    Acknowledgment Number                      |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |  Data |           |U|A|P|R|S|F|                               |
> | Offset| Reserved  |R|C|S|S|Y|I|            Window             |
> |       |           |G|K|H|T|N|N|                               |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |           Checksum            |         Urgent Pointer        |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                    Options                    |    Padding    |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                             data                              |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ 
>
>                         TCP Header Format
>
>       Note that one tick mark represents one bit position.
>
>                            Figure 3.
> ```

Comment: It should be noted that a `0` option marks the end of the option list and the padding is composed of all `0`s - so the padding can be regarded as an option.